# Java package naming when domain and app name are the same

Tags: java, android

I'm curious about best practices around Java package naming when the domain name and the class name would be the same.

For example, if I am creating a new android app called Foo and my domain is foo.com

The java package name would be

```
com.foo.foo
```

correct?

Is there a better way to name it or am I overthinking this?

Comment: That depends if you later plan to add a `com.foo.bar`. If not, I would go for the shorter name. Examples of this strategy are `org.junit` or `org.easymock`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the convention is always

```
domain.domainname.package[.subpackage].Class
```

(where `subpackage` is optional). The goal is to have a unique namespace for each project, to avoid namespace collisions, so shortening it is not a good idea.

to answer your question: `com.foo.foo` is a correct name if the second `foo` is the name of your project. if this project now contained a class `Bar`, the path would be `com.foo.foo.Bar`.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't like the look of the repetition in the name but if that's the standard then that's the standard!

Answer (score 2):

You may go through [package naming convention.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: I already read the package naming conventions, it does not answer my question. I am specifically looking at the case where the desired application name is the same as the domain name and whether or not there is an established best practice.